# Shadow Catcher blocks background image in 2.8

Tags: shadowcatcher

I'm pretty new to blender, and as I was getting used to 2.79, 2.8 landed and confused me ever more. I was wondering why the *Shadow Catcher* blocks the background image I set even if I checked *transparent* under *Film*.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Found out an answer. I should've just searched tutorials instead of troubleshooting forums instead.

Here's the link that helped.
https://www.blendernation.com/2017/04/17/use-new-blender-shadow-catcher/

So I apparently just needed to hit render and mix up some nodes in the compositor.

Thanks to the people who took their time to correct my post as well!